# Theme URLs problem

Tags: themes

I programmed a theme post (edit: probably that's the `single.php` template) which uses the  function `get_userdata( $_GET['p'] )`. But the main admin reformatted urls to this: `~/author/gamelaster` (default is `?author=1`) and now this is not working correctly.

> How do I get the id of Author in this URL format?

Or

> how do I get user slug + get id from database?

But, I cannot use the standard author functions/post functions(get_ID etc).

Comment: Please reformat your post and use proper English, single question and other marks only (which I already fixed).

Comment: Ok... To this.. I have a author.php , and userdata getting with function get_userdata($_GET['p']).. But, the URL has been changed and $_GET['p'] is not function.. And how to get a slug from new url? (author/gamelaster)

Comment: Or another.. The Default url is "?author=1", but its a changed to /author/gamelaster... Now $_GET['author'] (Lol, in last topic is a $_GET['p'] but it is $_GET['author']) not function and now, how to got a slug? (gamelaster)

Comment: There's an "edit" link below the post. Please don't comment, but instead _edit_ your question and make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on an "Author" page, and since you mentioned `author.php` it seems that you are, [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) will give you the author data, which it seems is what you want.

Try:

```
var_dump(get_queried_object());
```

I believe that is all the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

TRY

```
    // BUG : get_userdata()
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
    $user_info = get_userdata($_GET['p']);
    echo 'User ID : ' . $user_info->ID;
```

Comment: Can you please explain this answer?